# Python subprocess does not generate file like running through the command prompt does

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

If I run `.\program.exe -API api.json` in the command prompt, the program creates an api dump named api.json. I'm trying to do this through a Python script instead, but

```
with open("api.json", "w+") as file:
    subprocess.Popen(["program.exe", "-API", "api.json"], stdout=file, stderr=file)
```

does not generate the api dump -- api.json is blank after the operation completes. Am I doing something wrong? The program I'm using can be downloaded [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/setup.roblox.com/RobloxStudioLauncherBeta.exe). Running will install the program to %localappdata%\Roblox\versions, and you can copy everything into your project's working directory.

Answer (score 1):

`with open("api.json", "w+") as file:` creates your blank file, but your stand alone script already does this.  Just call the process with the argument and don't use `with`.

Comment: So just the second line, minus the stdout/err arguments? I was using that initially, but no file was being created.

Comment: Id have to see more code to make any other comments or suggestions

Comment: That's the only code being run -- there's nothing else aside from import statements. Passing the file as an argument doesn't seem to do the trick either. I edited in information to the question on how to install the program I'm using in-case it's program-specific.